# How to get Imageview Tag in imagePickerController to Update the correct ImageView

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, uiactionsheet

I have 6 Imageviews set with tags. In one tap on the imageview, i call the UIActionSheet to show button "Take Pic" & "select Pic". All this works fine.
in the imagePickerController where i finally set the selected image how do i know which Imageview to update the pic. 
Please let me know how i can pass my tag values to update the correct tapped Image.

here's my code.

viewDidLoad

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                             initWithTarget:self
                                             action:@selector(tappedImage:)];

tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[self.photo1 addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
[self.photo2 addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
[self.photo3 addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
[tapGestureRecognizer setDelegate:self];
```

tappedImage

```
- (void)tappedImage:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {
{

    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Add a Picture"
                              delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                              destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                              otherButtonTitles:@"Take Picture",@"Select Picture", nil];
            [actionSheet showInView:self.view];

}
```

}

imagePickerController

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[photo1 setImage:image];
```

}

For now all the images are being set to Photo1 Imageview.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an instance variable to your class to store the selected image. Then in your `tappedImage:` method you do:

```
_selectedImage = (UIImageView *)sender.view;
```

where `_selectedImage` is your instance variable of type `UIImageView *`.

Then in the `imagePickerController` method, you can do:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [_selectedImage setImage:image];
}
```

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy... but now only one imageview is recognizing  the tap. like only photo2 tap is working and pulling up the actionSheet. when i click on photo1 its not even going in the (void)tappedImage: code.

Comment: The code I posted would not cause such a problem. I think the problem is that you can't use a single gesture recognizer with more than one view. Each view needs its own recognizer.

Comment: well, your code is perfect to get the tag info... thank u. i was just wondering if u could fing an error in my code. for each image view, i hv a seperate gesture recognizers.

Comment: No, in the code you posted you create one gesture recognizer and try to use it with 3 separate views. As I stated, you need a different gesture recognizer for each view. In other words, create 3 separate gesture recognizers. Use one per view.

Comment: i changed my code to  tapGestureRecognizer1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tappedImage:)];
    tapGestureRecognizer1.delegate = self;
    [self.photo1 addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer1];
    
    
    tapGestureRecognizer2 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tappedImage:)];
    tapGestureRecognizer2.delegate = self;
    [self.photo2 addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer2];
and it works ...:-) but is there a better way then repeating the same line of code for 6 gesture recognizers...???

Comment: Write a little helper method to create the gesture recognizer or use a loop.